# Why firefox console showing unnecessary things

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, console

i want just to see the content of the div but firefox is showing me a lot of null and non unnecessary attributes. please help me to hide those attibutes??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpmlq.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's part of the page itself. Using Chrome to post, but using Firefox I get that thing on a test website:

[image: What I experienced]

On Chrome the same thing happens:

[image: What I experienced on Chrome]

Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="this-is-an-id" class="this-is-a-class" custom-attribute="this-is-a-custom-attribute">This is the content of the div</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it happend when i print an element in the console

Comment: @WISSEM I cannot help. Sorry!